# dynamically create ASP.NET radar chart

Tags: asp.net, charts

how can I dynamically create series for an ASP.NET (C#,vs2010) radar chart? I'm loading data from DB and I don't know how many series would I have, how can I draw a radar chart with dynamic series?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an unknown number of series, you may want to allow your users to select/hide some of them in order no to clutter the graph. Or you may even want to "play" with the period of time being observed.

In order to avoid too many round trips with the server, a proposed approach would be to let the server gather the data, and distribute them as JSON. Then, instead of having your server handle the load of generating a fixed image for each request, this task would be offloaded to the client and dealt with by specialized javascript libraries.

For instance, this **[page](http://www.larsko.org/v/euc/)** draws a radial graph by leveraging the **[d3.js](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/)** library and allow the user to visualize the evolution of the series over time thanks to a slider.

In this case, the series are being fetched from the server through the [d3.json](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Requests#wiki-d3_json) method. However, the library is able to handle xml or even **[csv](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/CSV)**.

The source code of the page is worth a peek :)

**Note:** [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/), another popular library should add a chart graph to its rendering capabilities in [march 2012](http://www.highcharts.com/support/roadmap).